# improve linear search for KNN efficiency w/ NumPY

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to calculate the distance of each point in the testing set from each point in the training set:

This is what my loop looks like right now:

```
 for x in testingSet
    for y in trainingSet
        print numpy.linalg.norm(x-y)
```

Where testingSet and trainingSet are numpy arrays where each row of the two sets hold the feature data for one example.

However, it's running extremely slowly, taking more than 10 minutes since my data set is bigger (testing set of 3000, training set of ~10,000). Does this have to do with my method or am I utilizing numPY incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you naively iterate over your data, and loops are slow in python. Instead, use sklearn [pairwise distance functions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html), or even better - use sklearn [efficient nearest neighbour](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) search (like BallTree or KDTree). If you do not want to use sklearn, there is also a [module in scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html). Finally you can do "matrix tricks" to compute this, since

```
|| x - y ||^2 = <x-y, x-y> = <x,x> + <y,y> - 2<x,y>
```

you can do (assuming your data is in matrix form given as X and Y):

```
X2 = (X**2).sum(axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
Y2 = (Y**2).sum(axis=1).reshape((1, -1))
distances = np.sqrt(X2 + Y2 - 2*X.dot(Y.T))
```